# checkbox unusable - contact form 7 - Wordpress - MDBootstrap

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, mdbootstrap

Guys I have a very simple but complex problem in the same way.

I'm building my custom wordpress theme, using the MDB framework (Bootstrap material design).

And when I go to implement my form via wordpress cf7, the two styles conflict. Generating a problem that the checkbox is displayed but cannot be used.

I have been around a lot in google but I have not found any resolution.

How can I solve this?

Checkbox in mdb:

```
<!-- Default checked -->
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultChecked2" checked>
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultChecked2">Default checked</label>
</div>
```

Checkbox in cf7:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultChecked2">Default checked</label>
  [checkbox checkbox-887 id:defaultChecked2 class:custom-control-input]
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be hard to troubleshoot without a link to the malfunctioning checkbox.
However if I were to take a wild guess you could try this CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"] { 
-webkit-appearance: checkbox; 
}
```

Add that CSS to your theme's CSS. And if it fails send us a link.